# Hypergeometric distribution with multiple observations

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

This is my maiden question on Math stack exchange so do forgive me if I am not following any community norms or not presenting my questions as clear as it should be.

I am trying to find probabilities with hypergeometric distribution. I will be working with multiple random and independent observations being made at the same time and I am unclear of how to handle it in the manner that is presented to me.

The usual probability mass function ("**PMF**") is this: $$P(x)=\frac{\binom{k}{x}\cdot\binom{N-k}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

For the purposes of this post, I shall provide a hypothetical question here to illustrate the issue,

Suppose a certain disease affects 400 ($k$) people in a population of 20,000 people ($N$). If a random sample of 1,000 people ($n$) is taken and tested without replacement what is the probability that exactly 20 ($x$) of them have the disease if people were taken and tested,

1. one at a time?
2. 10 at a time?
3. 7 at a time?

**For scenario 1**

If I am making one observation at a time, I can proceed with using the PMF as per normal such that,
$$P(x=20|N=20,000, n=1,000, k=400)$$
$$P(x=20)=\frac{\binom{400}{20}\cdot\binom{20,000-400}{1,000-20}}{\binom{20,000}{1,000}}$$

**For scenario 2**

If I am making 10 observations at a time, my understanding is that, all I would need to do is to divide all the variables $(x, N, n, k)$ by 10.

This means that $P(x=20|N=20,000, n=1,000, k=400)$ adjusted for 10 events being observed at a time would give us,
$$P(x=2|N=2,000, n=100, k=40)$$
$$P(x=2)=\frac{\binom{40}{2}\cdot\binom{2,000-40}{100-2}}{\binom{2,000}{100}}$$

**For scenario 3**

Now, this is where things get hairy. If I am making 7 observations at a time, I cannot simply divide all the variables by 7 like the way I did in scenario 2. I will have remainders for everything, especially for $n$ where I will have a remainder of 6 and I have **no idea** what to do with it.

In summary I am asking whether,

1. dividing all variables $(x, N, n, k)$ by the number of observations being made at the same time a mathematically sound way to handle multiple observations in hypergeometric distributions? (aka is my method in scenario 2 correct)
2. if so, how do I go about handling remainders in $n$?
3. how would you handle scenario 3?

I have attempted to work with ChatGPT on this issue. However, it is, to say the least, rather unreliable at math. Thus, it took me some time to discover this community and to ask this question.

Comment: *"If I am making 10 observations at a time, my understanding is that, all I would need ..."* Please explain this scenario with more details. For instance, how many successes do you have?

Comment: @callculus42 - What I meant by dividing all the variables by 10 was this:
$P(x=2|N=2,000, n=100,  k=40)=\frac{\binom{40}{2}\cdot\binom{2000-40}{100-2}}{\binom{2000}{100}}$. Hope this clarifies your question!

Comment: "I have attempted to work with ChatGPT on this issue. However, it is, to say the least, rather unreliable at math." This is true!

Comment: Alright, I have made some edits to this post to make it clearer for everyone. I hope that some wise mathemagician out there can is kind enough to bestow some of their wisdom onto me

Comment: Forgetting scenario 3, I am not even sure what the event is in scenario 2 whose probability you are computing. You are taking the sample of $1000$ and dividing it into $100$ groups of $10$. Then for each group you are... doing what? And which outcomes of your tests would leads to you saying "okay, $20$ people in the sample have the disease"?

Comment: I mean, if we are just asking "what is the probability that exactly $20$ people in a sample of $1000$ have the disease?" then it is irrelevant whether you test them one at a time, seven at a time, ten at a time, or whether you have them all take tests simultaneously while doing jumping jacks. It is going to be $\frac{\binom{400}{20}\cdot\binom{20,000-400}{1,000-20}}{\binom{20,000}{1,000}}$ either way. However, if we are doing something weird with the tests such that we don't know exactly who has the disease after testing, then we are asking a different question. Which question are you asking?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Correct me if my understanding on this topic is wrong, I am new in this area. My understanding is that, if you were to take and test the entire n
 at one go (1,000), that would just make it a Binomial distribution whereby $P(x=20)=\binom{1,000}{20}(0.02)^{20}(1−0.02)^{1,000−20}$. (note: success rate of 0.02 is derived from 400/20,000). This would imply that, as we observe more events without replacement at the same time, the hypergeometric distribution becomes more binomial. Thus, some adjustments will need to be made to the PMF if we are observing multiple events simultaneously

Comment: The difference between the hypergeometric distribution and the binomial is not whether you test them "in one go" or not; it's whether you test with replacement. If you test 1000 *different* people, it's hypergeometric. If you sample a random person 1000 times over and over again, not taking any precautions against picking the same person multiple times, it's binomial. Is this the distinction you want to draw?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I understand the distinction between Hypergeometric and Binomial distribution being that one is without and the other is with replacement, respectively. I believe that perhaps my understanding may have been overly clouded by an example regarding their distinction being akin to "drawing 5 cards from a poker deck" vs "cutting 5 cards from a poker deck". Seeking clarification from ChatGPT proved pointless and unreliable. I believe that your explanation makes much more sense. My apologies if I'm asking too "basic" of a question in this forum. Self-learning math is challenging.